# Adjusting global object properties within a function

Tags: javascript, function, object, properties, global-variables

My Question:
**How do I get my switch to recognize the global object property currentSpace of variable guy?**

Ok, so for a project, I have an object, let's call him guy.

```
var guy = new Object (); 
guy.currentSpace = "";
```

The problem I'm having is that in a later function where I change the value of guy and display him in an empty paragraph

```
function startTheGame () {
guy["currentSpace"] = space1.name;
var para = document.getElementById("empty");
guy["currentSpace"] = "Current space: " + space1.name;
para.innerHTML = guy.currentSpace;
};
```

this code successful displays the value of currentSpace. however, later on in my switch statement, the switch is unable to pick up on the value of guy.currentSpace. it **should** be equal to space1 because I changed the value of currentSpace from an empty string to the name property of the space1 object (**note**: I **do** have an object prototype for an individual space and have created ten space objects, all with a name. don't worry about that)

```
switch (guy.currentSpace) {
    case "space1":
    space1.visited = true;
    break;
    }

case "space2":
space2.visited = true;
break;

default:
    para.innerHTML = guy.currentSpace;
```

instead, it goes straight to the default case. something is amiss, it was unable to change the value of para because it
said it was undefined, but I thought that the variable para was already   declared so all I had to do was assign it to something else

Comment: Why the brace after the first `break`?

Comment: the one after the break is an accident there used to be an if statement there. the point is that the switch is unable to recognize the guy.currentSpace value